# Using business intelligence to generate reports

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, business-intelligence

We have a custom database and some web application for our clients, I will develop a interface for them to generate report(s).

They will have options to select -- which will in result query a single database or records from all tables for a specific clientId (we have 1000s of clients using same custom database), then output it in either Excel, pdf etc..

I will need to check security in code behind as well but it's a minor thing for now.

**My Question**

Should I use entity framework to get required data then design a interface using Html and give user what they want. May create more then 1 application pages too.

OR

Is there any business intelligence in SharePoint I could use here AND if it is better way then above ?

I am using SharePoint 2013 foundation with SQL Server 2012